# Log4j not working when execute file .jar

Tags: log4j, executable-jar

I have the problem running executable .jar file. I've created a project which contains a log4j.properties file. It works just fine when I start it from eclipse, but when I export it with option runable jar file on eclipse to executable .jar file and try to run it with command:

```
java -jar myfile.jar
```

Run susscess but check log4j-application.log don't wite log

My architecture project

```
--src
    --excute
            Main.java
--log4j.properties
```

---

```
public class Main {
...
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main .class);
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
    logger.info("done");
   }
}
```

log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=debug,stdout,file
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Rirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Run jar file in folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WFQH.png)

Comment: Is your log4j.properties in the classpath?

Comment: This is content my classpath file:
 <classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/ojdbc14.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
 </classpath>

Comment: If you run it from commandline the eclipse classpath will not be used

Comment: I put the file log4j.properties in the same directory that contains the .classpath file

Comment: log4j.properties is not in your class path when u run through command line. you can configure -Dlog4j.configuration=${path to your properties file} while executing java command

Comment: @hung The .classpath file is not used from command line. It is only visible for eclipse

Comment: @Jens Where can I configure Dlog4j.configuration while executing java command?

Comment: @hung `java -Dlog4j.configuration=${path to your properties file} -jar myfile.jar`

Comment: I try it but not work: don't wite log to C:\log4j-application.log -->
java -Dlog4j.configuration=D:/log4j.properties -jar myfile.jar

Comment: I solved the problem.
The reason is that I selected wrong option export jar file.
User -Dlog4j.configuration=${path to your properties file} is not necessary
Thanks @Jens

Comment: @SnehalPatel I think it should be `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/To/log4j.properties`